# PowerBI: how calculate percentage for each row in a column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like this:

```
id   count
----------
1    200
2    100
```

I would like to have a column like this:

```
id   count  pct
-------------------
1    200    200/300
2    100    100/300
```

I would like to create a column when I calculate the percentage of count value of the total count of the column.

How can I do this ? I tried DAX or custom column but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [ALL](https://dax.guide/all/) statement to remove filtering.

It will be a measure:

```
DIVIDE(SUM('TableName'[Count]), CALCULATE(SUM('TableName'[Count]), ALL()))
```

Change the 'TableName' to the name of the table in your dataset.

CALCULATE(SUM('TableName'[Count]), ALL()) will sum up all the values in the column, as it ignores the slicing by the 'id' column.